# ValueError: I/O operation on closed file on indented file with "with"block

Tags: python, csv

```
with open('C:\\Users\\Download.csv', 'r') as file :
    filedata = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    for c in range(sum(1 for row in filedata)):
        for d in range(80):
            data_found = data_to_match.search(filedata)
            if data_found != None:
                data_found_new = str(data_found.group(0)).replace(',','.')
                filedata = filedata.replace(str(data_found.group(0)) , data_found_new)
        for e in range(80):
            data_found_2 = data_to_match_2.search(filedata)
            if data_found_2 != None:
                data_found_2_new = str(data_found_2.group(0)).replace(', ', '; ')
                filedata = filedata.replace(str(data_found_2.group(0)),data_found_2_new)

with open('C:\\Users\\Download.csv', 'w', newline='') as file2:
    writer = csv.writer(file2, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    writer.writerows(filedata)
```

This give me an ValueError: I/O operation on closed file ( for the row writer.writerows(filedata)). I tried to look the error up but all I found were people who didnt indent their code. But atleast for my eyes this doesnt look like the problem here.

Edit: example Input

first row of the file:
"Datum","Uhrzeit","Zeitzone","Name","Typ","Status","Währung","Brutto","Gebühr",
"Netto","Absender E-Mail-Adresse","Empfänger E-Mail-Adresse",
"Transaktionscode","Lieferadresse","Adress-Status",
"Artikelbezeichnung","Artikelnummer","Versand- und Bearbeitungsgebühr",
"Versicherungsbetrag","Umsatzsteuer","Option 1 Name","Option 1 Wert",
"Option 2 Name","Option 2 Wert","Zugehöriger Transaktionscode",
"Rechnungsnummer","Zollnummer","Anzahl","Empfangsnummer","Guthaben",
"Adresszeile1","Adresszusatz","Ort","Bundesland","PLZ","Land","Telefon",
"Betreff","Hinweis","Ländervorwahl","Auswirkung auf Guthaben"

second row of the file:
"02.03.2019","11:25:51","PST","Delivery Hero Germany GmbH - Lieferheld",
"PayPal Express-Zahlung","Abgeschlossen","EUR","-12,35","0,00",
"-12,35","jjjjjjj@gmail.com","cc_finance@deliveryhero.com","00000000000",
"111 jjjjjjj Straße, aaaaaaaa, 55555, Deutschland","Bestätigt",
"1111111111111","11111111","0,00","","0,00","","","","","",
"444444444444",
"Lieferheld_DE:11111111111111111:111111111:11111:11111111111:paypal","1","",
"-12,35","111 jjjjjjj Straße","","aaaaaaaa","","555555","Deutschland",
"","99999999999999","","DE","Soll"

Comment: Please share a sample input file.

Comment: After you read all the lines with the first for, filedata will close, That's why you can't access it inside the second with.

Comment: @daniboy000 If I want to write and read the file I would have to open it in write mode then, wouldnt I? And define a csv reader and writer in it?

Comment: if you `open` and then `read everything` and then try to `read` some more, the second `read` will fail. It's not clear how you want or expect this to work but a common workaround is to read all the lines into an array, then operate on that array.

Comment: @JannickL I think it's better for you to write the output in a different file.

Comment: @JannickL Another question here is why are you replacing ',' for '.' and ';' since you are using ',' as delimiter. There won't be any ',' in the output of csv.reader.

Comment: `sum(1 for row in filedata)` consumes the file iterator completely. As a result, you never actually *enter* the `for c in range(...)` loop, so `filedata` is still a `csv` wrapper around the now closed file. (There also appears to be a misunderstanding about what `filedata` is; it's an instance of `csv.reader`, not a string containing the data from the file.)

Comment: @chepner: You enter the loop, because the `sum` initializes a `range`, which actually loops. But `filedata` is an exhausted iterator at that point. This code shouldn't work at all; `data_to_match.search(filedata)` should raise a `TypeError` when it's called.

Comment: Ah, right, I ignored the call to `range`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

variable "filedata" in inside with open block and it is csv object. So once you get out of this block, this file wll get closed automatically and you are using same filedata object in 2nd with open block.

Better to take a variable and put all value of csv object and pass in 2nd with open block.

```
f2 = []
with open('C:\\Users\\Download.csv', 'r') as file :
    filedata = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    for x in filedata:
        f2.append(x)

with open('C:\\Users\\Download.csv', 'w') as file2:
    writer = csv.writer(file2, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    writer.writerows(f2)
```

Solution 2:
Instead of with open in 1st block, use only open.

```
f_obj = open('C:\\Users\\Download.csv', 'r')
filedata = csv.reader(f_obj, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')

with open('C:\\Users\\Download.csv', 'w') as file2:
    writer = csv.writer(file2, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    writer.writerows(filedata)
```